# How to install WireMock using Puppet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppet, deb, wiremock

Trying to find a way to install WireMock using Puppet.

Can I do it without Docker?

Answer (score 1):

It (the WireMock JAR) is in [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.tomakehurst%7Cwiremock%7C2.6.0%7Cpom).

Use your desired tool (`wget` etc) to pull [the artifact](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/2.6.0/wiremock-2.6.0-javadoc.jar) directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following shell scripts to [download](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/) and run WireMock in a standalone mode, e.g.:

#### 1.58

```
mkdir -vp /opt/WireMock && cd /opt/WireMock
wget http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/1.58/wiremock-1.58-standalone.jar
java -jar wiremock-1.58-standalone.jar --port 9999
```

#### 2.6.0

```
mkdir -vp /opt/WireMock && cd /opt/WireMock
wget http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock-standalone/2.6.0/wiremock-standalone-2.6.0.jar
java -jar wiremock-standalone-2.6.0.jar --port 9000 --verbose --print-all-network-traffic --record-mappings
```

---

<sup>Note: Use `--root-dir` to point to your mapping files. Add `&` at the end to run the process in the background.</sup>

See: [Running as a Standalone Process](http://wiremock.org/docs/running-standalone/).